# Removed dmraid but still No Hardddisk found for Mac Model A1289

Tags: dmraid

I'm running Live CD for Ubuntu 14.04 inside Mac Machine Model A1289
I only have 1 harddisk which earlier formatted with NTFS
But the Live CD does not detect the harddisk. I've run sudo apt-get remove dmraid and try re-installing still no Harddisk seen. I'm getting mssg "update-initramfs is disabled since running on read-only media". I try sudo apt-get purge dmraid and same result. Is it bcoz im running from Live CD ?
Pls help. Thank you.